# Undefined is not a function for axios create

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following:

```
var axios_main = require('axios')
const axios = axios_main.create({ baseURL: 'https://somesite.com/', });
```

And on .create I get:

```
Uncaught Error

undefined is not a function
```

I'm not sure how to handle this.